# I need parent <---> child directive communication within a table with sibling rows

Tags: html, angularjs

I am needing to develop a table that uses some more complex UI operations than a typical table.  At first glance there could be 1 single row, then when clicked on, the row "expands" and 3 more rows appear below it.  From a data-model point of view, these 3 rows are children of the parent (Parent row displays Order information, child rows display individual product info), but in the DOM these 4 rows are all seperate siblings.

Since they are siblings in the DOM, it makes it hard to write an Angular directive using the `require` attribute to communicate with the parent controller API.  I also cannot wrap my `<tr>`'s in a parent element that I use as the API because HTML5 standards don't let us do something like

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <div my-parent-directive>
            <tr my-order-row></tr>
            <tr my-product-row></tr>
            <tr my-product-row></tr>
            <tr my-product-row></tr>
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This goes against proper HTML structure, therefore I have no idea how I can get this functionality using directives that communicate to one another.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at this - http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can pass the same bound object into each directive (the parent and children) and then watch for changes on the object in each directive and take the appropriate action.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <div my-parent-directive shared-attribute="someAttribute">
     <tr my-order-row   shared-attribute="someAttribute"></tr>
     <tr my-product-row shared-attribute="someAttribute"></tr>
     <tr my-product-row shared-attribute="someAttribute"></tr>
     <tr my-product-row shared-attribute="someAttribute"></tr>
   </div>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Assuming that you declare the object in $scope of the controller the directive is housed in.

```
$scope.someAttribute = {sharedData: 7, today: new Date(), etc... };
```

In each of your directives you will need to make sure that the attribute is two way data-bound (or at least in the directives that will be making modifications.

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', ['$filter', // inject dependencies
    function($filter) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A', 
            scope: {
                sharedAttribute: '=', // in HTML this will be shared-attribute="someObject" , "=" means two way data binding, "@" would mean one way binding... essentially a string, "&" would mean you want to pass a function name. etc...
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 


                 scope.$watch('sharedAttribute', function(newValue, oldValue){
                     // do something when object changes
                     // you could change the above to 'sharedAttribute.someProperty' to watch a property of the object
                     console.log('sharedAttribute chaged', sharedAttribute);
                 });
            }
        }
     }
 });
```

**Update**

Regarding your concerns, you can communicate a simple boolean for showing child rows as such:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <div my-parent-directive shared-attribute="someObject" ng-click='someObject.showChildren=!someObject.showChildren'>
     <tr my-order-row   shared-attribute="someObject" ng-show="someObject.showChildren"></tr>
     <tr my-product-row shared-attribute="someObject" ng-show="someObject.showChildren"></tr>
     <tr my-product-row shared-attribute="someObject" ng-show="someObject.showChildren"></tr>
     <tr my-product-row shared-attribute="someObject" ng-show="someObject.showChildren"></tr>
   </div>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The shared object controls visibility of children via ng-show, or you could use ng-class as well.

I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve, but this would completely address the directives being able to communicate with each other.

The great thing here is that once you modify the value in one directive, it will be changed in all the other directives that share that value.

Also, don't feel that it's "wrong" to put a isDroppedDown boolean on each of the JSON objects in the Array in the table; this is actually a "good" thing. It's called pre-processing, meaning that you would want to process the object first and then make it available in scope, then angular doesn't have to muck around with the details, it just processes the display of the object. And when you make changes to the object, it will update the view live.

You may feel this is a bit 'memory intensive' adding attributes to multiple objects (especially those in a repeater), but this is a good way to do things as you can keep track of object state through the flow of the application.

Comment: Hmmmm interesting.  I think that could work and it is more elegant than creating a service just to handle this table. Thanks

Comment: glad to help. Sometimes $watch doesn't work for me for some reason, if I pass in a simple object. If you run into $watch not firing, what you want to do is pass a object with attributes or a collection (array) and watch that.

Comment: I am still not sure how I could communicate something like a simple boolean to show/hide the 3 sub-rows once the parent row is clicked. I can create a directive with a controller that has a `isDroppedDown` variable that gets toggled when the user clicks on the `<tr>`. Then my 3 other directives will need that value, but it is sitting on the `my-order-row`.  I understand that you can communicate between the 4 rows using a parent $scope, but it feel "wrong" to put a `isDroppedDown` boolean on each of my JSON objects in the Array used to populate the table

Comment: Hey, so I think I just thought of another possible solution to allow directive communication.  According to the W3C Standards (http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3), I can have multiple `<tbody>` elements inside my `<table>`. Therefore, I can wrap each of my Order's inside their own `<tbody>` which will act as my parent API directive

Comment: See update above. You have valid concerns, let me know what you choose. Hope I solved the issue of communicating between directives. Also, you can try sharing the scope of a directive with it's children by declaring the children within the template of the parent controller. Then you can create a controller for the directive and controllers for the children, and then communicate via $broadcast and $emit

Comment: Thanks, I will play around with both solutions and see what one tends to work better!